# show video in label

Tags: python, opencv, tkinter, raspberry-pi

I am currently working on a project which includes showing a video in a gui.
The software runs on a raspberry pi and is written in python. I am using tkinter for the gui.

When i run the playvideo function just the last frame is shown.
First i thought the raspberry is to slow, but also after inserting a sleep(3) nothing changed.

Does anyone see my error?

```
    def play_video():
        cap = cv2.VideoCapture('video.h264')
        ret = True
        while(ret):
            ret, frame = cap.read()
            time.sleep(3)
            if ret:
                print "in"
                img = Image.fromarray(frame)
                imgtk = ImageTk.PhotoImage(image=img)
                show_video_label .imgtk = imgtk
                show_video_label .configure(image=imgtk)
                show_video_label._image_cache = imgtk 

        cap.release()
```

Thanks a lot!!!

Comment: What you most likely need is: override the paint method somewhere. What's happening right now is, there's a single thread that's painting the UI. However, the play_video() take up the entire thread - thus you end up with just the last frame.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot use while loops like this in UI applications as it prevents processing the system events. You must keep `mainloop` processing events to continue to be active.

In this case you should create a function that captures and displays a single frame then in a 'start_video' function, use the `after` method to schedule a call to capture a frame and each time you capture a frame use `after` again to schedule the next capture. A `stop_video` method could just cancel the last `after` if you preserve the token returned by the `after` call.